# Load data under jQueryUI tabs with no AJAX call

Tags: jquery-ui

I want to load data by on click of the jQuery ui tabs. If I provide the links in tabs href then its automatically calling by AJAX, but i want to get data by normal request. 
basically my page is search page where there are different searches will perform on each Tabs and also maintain the search states. If I use AJAX then I cant save the search states .

please help me. i shall very thankful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply injecting the content you want to display straight into the tab's body and not setting anything ajax specific?

Essentially you should add a listener to the tab menu and then injecting the content into the tab's body. Something along the lines of:

```
$("#tabs ul li a").click( function () {
                                  var id = $(this).attr("href");
                                  $(id).html( fetch-content() );
                         })
```

That should be it.